# Using Swift classes in playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm playing with Swift; I downloaded https://github.com/FahimF/SQLiteDB and, when called from .swift file it runs fine ..I connect and get query results as:

```
        let db = SQLiteDB.sharedInstance()
        if let data = db.query("SELECT * FROM squadre") {
            for row in data {
                println(row["nome"]?.asString())
            }
        }
```

I would like to do the same thing in a playground but cannot use SQLiteDB inside the playground ... I get a:

> "Use of unresolved identifier SQLiteDB"

Which is the way to use custom classes from playground?

Answer (score 1):

you must integrate SQLiteDB in the Playground Projekt.

[image]

Comment: I have created a playground file inside the same project; do i have to create a new Playground project?

Comment: Ok this is amazing in a not good way ;-) 
With other words ... i don't know.